# Resend HTTP request with exact body || Paypal IPN Notifcation Handler

Tags: apex, paypal

I am trying to develop a salesforce IPN handler to receive Paypal payments notifications.

Paypal requires replying back with same received HTTP request body. I am not able to achieve this as Salesforce HTTP parameters are getting from Map with the alphabetic order. Accordingly, I receive always unverified request from Paypal.

Any Ideas or suggestions?

This is the controller class code that I have used:

```
        Map<String, String> parameterMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        String queryString = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        for (String parameterName : parameterMap.KeySet()) {
                queryString += '&' + parameterName + '=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(parameterMap.get(parameterName), 'UTF-8');
        }

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setEndpoint(getPaypalBaseURL());
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(queryString);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type'  , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', req.getBody().length().format());
        req.setTimeout(60000);

        system.debug('req body: ' + req.getBody());

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        String verificationResponse;

       // If this method is being called through a test method, create a sample response
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            // The sample response is based on a page parameter populated in the test method, called 'verification response'
            verificationResponse = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('verifcationResponse');
        } else {
            res = http.send(req);
            verificationResponse = res.getBody(); 
        }

        return verificationResponse.equalsIgnoreCase('VERIFIED');
```

Comment: Is there any reason your can't use `getURL()` instead of `getParameters()` and just parse the query string yourself?

Answer (score 0):

@dsharrison, the getURL() returns the encoded url, as that won't work.

@ahmed kishk, I think the issue is your may not be posting the request on correct URL, There is separate endpoints for sandbox and Production IPN. I had similar issue since couple of weeks and was able to solve it by using appropriate endpoint as below :

Send response messages back to PayPal:

- https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (for Sandbox IPNs)
- https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (for live IPNs)

[Check here for more details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/#specs)

Comment: All of the above links are unfortunately dead.